# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

While this may sound like a beginner 101 problem I think it is a bit more complicated.

I have two instances of SQL server, one is a log-shipped read/only standby copy of the master database that is used for reporting purposes.

They are both 64-bit SQL 2005, SP3.

The LogShipped Instance is: 9.00.4035.00 (Standard Edition)
The Original Instance is: 9.00.4035.00 (Enterprise Edition) in an Active / Passive Cluster.

Server collation is Latin1_General_CI_AI on both and they both run on Server 2003 64 bit.

I have a query that runs and executes fine on the master database server but it fails on the standby / read-only copy with a conversion of nvarchar to int.

The code is identical and i've copied and pasted it from the main instance query window just to double check.

Is there a bug in SQL server somewhere? I can paste the query if needed (its a bog-standard select with some in-line tables)

Just don't understand why it works on the one yet the log-shipped copy fails.

Any pointers is much appreciated.

-- Edit

I have found the culprit.. the transaction log database contains invalid data that isn't in the primary database.. quite why they are out of sych I do not know yet as the transaction log shipping is still working and I have no errors in the job-history.

Just a few orphaned records that are invalid that are not in the primary db.. how odd

Comment: In general this error sounds like you are probably getting different execution plans on the 2 different instances. In one of them it may be performing a cast before a filter and in the other the filter before the cast. The error message itself is strange though as `select cast(N'' as int)` returns `0` for me. Can you test what it returns for you on the problematic instance?

Comment: Hey, select cast(N'' as int) returns 0 on both instances. I'll have a look at the generated execution plans now..

Comment: Hey.. Same execution plans but the data isn't the same in both databases.. seems as though they have gone off-sync! I will investigate why as the stanbdy database is wrong but no errors in log-shipping. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you **sure** the data is the same?

If you try

```
select convert(int, char(10))
```

it will probably get a similar error, so your query will fail if the value you are converting is char(10), which may not be be obvious when viewing the data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. I foud the problem in that the data isn't the same.. even though the database is a transaction-logged shipped copy from the first one I have records in the secondary database that arn't in the primary database.. not sure how this can happen as the transaction logs have just finished restoring and the customers are still there..

Comment: @WesPrice please post your finding as an answer for the future reference of anyone.

Answer (score 0):

check any trigger if that is updating any view(having int for the specific column) based on your table